# s3 - file uploaded - message in multiple sqs queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

i want to be notified when file is uploaded to my s3 bucket. I know I can have sqs message or sns notification. What I need is a message send to multiple sqs queues. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure a SNS topic which will get the message when there is a upload to s3 bucket.
Then **subscribe** all the SQS queues to that SNS topic.
[See this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqssubscribe.html).

Comment: You need to enable event notification on the S3 bucket first, which can point to the SQS or SNS topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use s3 notification service for both SNS or SQS http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/

Answer (score 1):

now aws enable you to add s3 event to notify one sqs, only one and should be standard not fifo.
you can add more than one filter suffix or filter prefix but for the same standard sqs.
if you want to notify more than one queue standard/fifo you should have sns in the middle, which means s3 event to sns and all sqs are subscribed to that sns, also you can add multiple lambda functions and ec2 instances.